# Need an icon to represent a "Certification Authority"

Tags: icons

I'm (desperately) looking for an icon to represent a [Certification Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_authority), like the ones that sign X.509 certificates we use in secure e-commerce.

I need something which is concrete (not an abstract "idea" being depicted in a drawing) and conveys *affordability*, *solidity*, *importance*... I searched the Internet, finding stuff like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPublic-Key-Infrastructure.svg) which is not impressive at all.

Well, I've seen somewhere a CA represented by a building which you can often see, mostly in the USA, for libraries, courthouses, and town halls. The 'front' of the building, endowed with columns and a typical triangular pediment, looks like the White House and recalls a Greek temple, somewhat.

I couldn't find a clip-art or icon of this kind of building, maybe because I search using the wrong keywords.

Can you help me?

**EDIT**: I'm searching for something like **[this](http://office.microsoft.com/it-it/images/results.aspx?qu=banca&ctt=1#ai%3aMC900234526%7Cmt:1%7Cis:0%7C)**, but less 'stylized' and less clip-artish.

Comment: Even I don't think I would draw the line between "Greek looking building" and CA. Why not use something that looks like a certificate(http://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/2/2e/Artwork_BluecurveLibrary_bluecurve-certificate.png)?

Comment: The kind of building you're after is called a Capitol Building.  Here's a clipart example: http://www.clipartguide.com/_pages/0511-0712-2617-2728.html

Comment: @Ben Brocka: it's not for its greek-ness PhilipW: thanks

Comment: @gd1 still, it's not a common association, unless it's well known in your user base I would avoid it. Such a symbol makes me think "bank" or "wall street," CA wouldn't even be on my list. If anything it seems much more abstract than the certificate.

Comment: @Ben: I think I'll put a certificate upon the building, in the upper-left corner or in the bottom-right one

Comment: @gd1: Who is your target audience?

Comment: @JohnGB: University professors (very expert audience)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a badge (police-style badge, I mean)? Recognizable and it implies authority and trust.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the icon? Are you looking for a static logo or the icon on an active UI element (that can be clicked)?

For the UI element, the icon by itself will almost certainly be insufficient for recognition -- additional text is necessary either on the button itself or at least in a tooltip. Icon itself is almost irrelevant, as there is no established convention. Padlock, police badge, official building with columns, certificate/diploma with seal -- almost anything would work, as long as it's consistent with your other icons.